# How could it be possible to pass arguments to inner function inside another one with same name?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, arrow-functions

I'm new to JavaScript and learning it from Freecodecamp. here is one of script while learning higher order arrow function.
I can't understand it completely, is there two function with same name in the example below? where do the arguments passed in? inside inner function or outer one?
if the answer is outer function, how could it be possible as the outer function seems like doesn't take any argument.

```
const increment = (function(){
    return function increment(number, value){
        return number + value;
    };
})();
console.log(increment(5,2));
```

Comment: Where is the "_higher order __arrow__ function_"? In your example there are two function expressions, the outer-one is anonymous, and the inner-one is named. The name of the named function expression is visible _inside that function_ only. Your code assigns the result of the IIFE to `increment` variable (that is the function defined inside the IIFE), and when you calling that function in `console.log`, you're also passing the arguments.

Comment: I have same question about Arrow function, but FreeCodeCamp tutor in this video says lets write higher order arrow function at 2:53.04.

https://youtu.be/PkZNo7MFNFg?t=10384

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function assigned to the `increment` constant is wrapped an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). This means that this function is, like the name suggests, immediately called and executed. It then returns a reference to the function declared inside the IIFE.

```
const increment = (function(){
  return function increment(number, value){
    return number + value;
  };
})();
```

This results is the same as this:

```
const increment = function increment(number, value){
  return number + value;
};
```

This is a named function expression. Both the variable and the function are allowed to have the same name if you follow this pattern. Try defining it in the console like how it is in the second code block.

The difference here is that the variable `increment` is simply a reference to the function `increment`.

But in your case the `function increment` was defined **inside** the anonymous function's scope. The `increment` function name is then only available in the scope of that anon function. The reference to the `increment` function is then returned.

Though the IIFE can be omitted as it doesn't do anything different. It could add some value if you want to incorporate a closure to hide some variables, for example:

```
const increment = (function(){
  const hiddenValue = 2;
  return function increment(number, value){
    return number + value + hiddenValue;
  };
})();
```

Now everytime you call `increment` the `hiddenValue` will be added to the formula. This way you can create a kind of global variable which lives in the scope of the IIFE and won't pollute your actual global scope.

Comment: Yet a couple of nitpicks. The function inside the IIFE is not declared, it's still a function expression. Also, `increment` _function name_ is only available in that function itself, nevertheless it is returned or not (though that's a bit obfuscated in the code, as the variable the function is assigned to, holds the same name). That's just one of the differences between declared functions and named function expressions.

Comment: "*The `increment` function name is then only available in the scope of that anon function*" - it's still just a named function expression, there is no declaration of a variable. The result is *exactly* the same as without the IIFE.

Comment: Thanks for the input, gentlemen. If there is any more to edit, please let me know. I'm learning from it as well.

Comment: Damn, needed that to solve a pre-interview challenge.

Answer (score 1):

```
return function increment(number, value){
    return number + value;
};
```

In the code above the function name does not matter and removing it would change nothing.
The only function name that matters to the outside world is the constant name.
Here as pseudo-code:

```
const increment = (anonymous func (return a func)) (self call);
```

Without the LHS (left hand side) assignment everything would be lost after execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can put two function inside each other and call the function inside the main function
but outside the other

```
function firstOne(){
  console.log('first function is working.')
  function secondOne(){
    console.log('second function is working')
  }secondOne();
}firstOne()
```